# List<> too many loops

Tags: c#

My foreach loops one too many times, and I fail to understand why. The program should go trough 1-100 and sum up the fourth power of each digit.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;    

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int sum = 0;            
        string temp = "";           
        List<int> digits = new List<int>();

        for (long i = 2; i < 100; i++)
        {
            temp = i.ToString();

            for(int y = 0; y < temp.Length; y++)
            {
                digits.Add(Convert.ToInt32(temp.Substring(y,1)));

                foreach(int j in digits)
                {
                    sum += Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(j,4));                      
                    Console.WriteLine("foreach loop: i = {0}, y = {1}, sum = {2}, j = {3}, digits count = {4}",i,y,sum,j,digits.Count);
                }                   
            }

            Console.WriteLine("i = {0}, sum = {1}", i, sum);                
            sum = 0;                    
            digits.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is output example

```
foreach loop: i = 10, y = 0, sum = 1, j = 1, digits count = 1
foreach loop: i = 10, y = 1, sum = 2, j = 1, digits count = 2
foreach loop: i = 10, y = 1, sum = 2, j = 0, digits count = 2
i = 10, sum = 2
foreach loop: i = 11, y = 0, sum = 1, j = 1, digits count = 1
foreach loop: i = 11, y = 1, sum = 2, j = 1, digits count = 2
foreach loop: i = 11, y = 1, sum = 3, j = 1, digits count = 2
i = 11, sum = 3
foreach loop: i = 12, y = 0, sum = 1, j = 1, digits count = 1
foreach loop: i = 12, y = 1, sum = 2, j = 1, digits count = 2
foreach loop: i = 12, y = 1, sum = 18, j = 2, digits count = 2
i = 12, sum = 18
```

Why does the foreach loop 3 times on a 2 digit number? The digit List is cleared after the loop

Lets take 10 for example.

```
temp = "10";
temp.Length = 2;
second for loop (y) runs twice. 1 < 2
digits gets filled twice
foreach runs three times
```

Comment: Then it seems like you loop all digits for every digit in the list. Two digits = one loop when adding first digit, then loop twice when adding second digit, because list contains two digits

Comment: It's because you have a loop that goes over the digits `for(int y = 0; y < temp.Length; y++)` and then you add the digit to a list that you then iterate over inside of that loop, so on the second time the `y` loop runs the list will now have two number in it and the `j` loop will go twice.  Just get rid of the `j` loop.

Comment: You need move `foreach` loop outside of the second `for`  loop.

Comment: Obviously :) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `foreach` loop seems create extra loops. It loop all digits in the list every time you adding next digit.

Here you don't even need `foreach` loop and list of digits too.

```
public static void Main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    string temp = "";

    for (long i = 2; i < 100; i++)
    {
        temp = i.ToString();
        for(int y = 0; y < temp.Length; y++)
        {
            int digit = Convert.ToInt32(temp.Substring(y,1));
            sum += Math.Pow(digit,4);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("i = {0}, sum = {1}", i, sum);
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

I prefer not using strings for handling integers, below is solution without converting between string and integer

```
public static void Main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (long i = 2; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for(int temp = i; temp > 0; temp /= 10)
        {
            int digit = temp % 10;
            sum += Math.Pow(digit,4);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("i = {0}, sum = {1}", i, sum);
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Start from behind and use modulo, clever. Nice and compact. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let's re-write it from scratch with *appropriate* names (what is `i` and `j`?) and comments:

```
 public static void Main() { 
   // we should scan numbers from 2 to 100
   for (int number = 2; number < 100; ++number) {
     string value = number.ToString();

     // digits: just the length of the string: "789" -> 3, "45" -> 2, "7" -> 1
     int digits = value.Length;

     // let's sum up the digits
     int sum = 0;

     // as we promised: sum up all 4th powers of the digits
     foreach (char c in value) {
       int digit = c - '0'; // notice, that c is character and we want int

       sum += Math.Pow(digit, 4);
     } 

     // time to output:
     Console.WriteLine("{0, 2}, sum = {1, 5}, digits count = {2, 1}",
       number, sum, digits);
   }
 }
```

*Linq* solution which is more *flexible*:

```
int startFrom = 2;
int endAt = 100;

var result = Enumerable
  .Range(startFrom, endAt - startFrom)
  .Select(number => new {
     number = number,
     digits = number.ToString().Length,
     sum = number
       .ToString()       
       .Select(c => c - '0')
       .Sum(x => Math.Pow(x, 4)) })
  .Select(item => $"{item.number, 2}, sum = {item.sum, 5}, digits = {item.digits, 1}"); 

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Output:

```
 2, sum =    16, digits count = 1
 3, sum =    81, digits count = 1
 4, sum =   256, digits count = 1
 5, sum =   625, digits count = 1
 6, sum =  1296, digits count = 1
 7, sum =  2401, digits count = 1
 8, sum =  4096, digits count = 1
 9, sum =  6561, digits count = 1
10, sum =     1, digits count = 2
...
98, sum = 10657, digits count = 2
99, sum = 13122, digits count = 2
```

Comment: Thanks - I always forget about `Enumerable.Range` when working with integers loops :)

Answer (score 0):

another (partially) `Linq` based solution:

```
public static void Main()
{
    for (long i = 2; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (var digit in i.ToString().Select(digit => int.Parse(digit.ToString())))
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(Convert.ToInt32(digit), 4));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("i = {0}, sum = {1}", i, sum);
    }
}
```